# Action_outside not called for my view

Tags: android, ontouch

I have created view like toast message. I need to find outside touch of my view(linear layout). 
I have set this flag to my main activity

```
Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, 
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
```

and set this touch listener for my view

```
mUndoView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getActionMasked()== MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
            {
                System.out.println("hai");
                Toast.makeText(mUndoView.getContext(), "Focus change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But i didn't receive action outside. Thanks advance.